# How to integrate lognormal equation?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, numerical-integration

The problem comes from the personal research

$h \sim \log N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then
$$f_H(h) = \frac{1}{h\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\log h-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right].$$

Here is a integration

$$P_l=\int_{-w}^{w}  
\int_{\frac{\ x_h}{\ y_h}(x_b-w)+l}^{\frac{\ x_h}{\ y_h}(x_b+w)+l}
P_r\left(
h\geqq\frac{\ z_h(y_b-l)}{y_h}
\right){}dy_bdx_b $$

in this integration
$$x_h,y_h,z_h,w,l $$

are constants. how to figure it out? My question is 
we can turn this into 
$$P_l=\int_{-w}^{w}  
\int_{\frac{\ x_h}{\ y_h}(x_b-w)+l}^{\frac{\ x_h}{\ y_h}(x_b+w)+l}
\int_{\frac{\ z_h(y_b-l)}{y_h}}^{+\infty} 
\space 
{
f_H(h)
}
\space dy_bdx_b .$$

But how to integrate the lognormal distribution?

Comment: Replacing $h$ by $e^y$ reduces this to a problem involving the Normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments by whuber:  Replacing $h$ by $e^y$ reduces this to a problem involving the Normal distribution.